# React Stripe PaymentElement

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe and React in order to execute code after payment but I have a few problems.

First, I get this poor design even though I follow the Stripe Dev team tutorial and they got a full card/other methods to pay design [stripe PaymentElement UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4t6Q.png)

Secondly, when I enter my name I get redirected to this page where I see the error below. When I approve the test, I get redirected to the success url even though I have specified not to redirect bu rather execute the code. On Stripe the payment was approved.

[Error when going to stripe checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKQx4.png)

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the full payment options UI and hwo can I execute the code I want on successful payment?

My code:
StripePayment.jsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { useHttpClient } from "../../hooks/http-hook";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import ModalWindow from "./ModalWindow";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";
import { FiX } from "react-icons/fi";

const StripePayment = (props) => {
  const [stripePromise, setStripePromise] = useState(null);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(null);

  const { sendRequest } = useHttpClient();

  const closeHandler = () => {
    props.cancel();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(`payment/configure`);
        setStripePromise(loadStripe(responseData.publishableKey));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    config();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPayment = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          `payment/create-payment-intent`,
          "POST",
          JSON.stringify({
            amount: 1,
            email: "***@abv.bg",
          }),
          {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
        );
        setClientSecret(responseData.clientSecret);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    loadPayment();
  }, []);

  const appearance = {
    theme: "stripe",
  };
  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance,
  };

  return (
    <ModalWindow static="static" show={true}>
      <div style={{ padding: "40px" }} className="center_section">
        <h1>Payment</h1>
        <FiX className="x_icon" onClick={closeHandler} />
        {stripePromise && clientSecret ? (
          <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
            <CheckoutForm
              clientSecret={clientSecret}
              onSuccess={props.onSuccess}
            />
          </Elements>
        ) : (
          <Loader />
        )}
      </div>
    </ModalWindow>
  );
};

export default StripePayment;
```

CheckoutForm.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  useStripe,
  useElements,
  PaymentElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { showError } from "../../redux/error";

const CheckoutForm = (props) => {
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false);

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs",
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    setIsProcessing(true);

    const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: `${window.location.origin}`,
      },
      redirect: "if_required",
    });

    //error
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      dispatch(showError(error.message));
      setIsProcessing(false);
      return;
    }

    //success
    if (paymentIntent && paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
      alert("contracts");
      setIsProcessing(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement options={paymentElementOptions} />
      <button
        type="submit"
        disabled={isProcessing || !stripe || !elements}
        className="rn-button-style--2 btn-solid mt--40"
      >
        {isProcessing ? "Processing..." : "Pay now"}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

server

controller

```
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_TEST, {
  apiVersion: "2022-08-01",
});

const getConfiguration = async (req, res, next) => {
  res
    .status(201)
    .json({ publishableKey: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY_TEST });
};

const postPaymentIntent = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { amount, email } = req.body;

  if (!amount || !email) {
    return next(new HttpError("No amount or email set, please try again", 500));
  }

  let paymentIntent;
  try {
    paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      currency: "eur",
      amount: 1,
      receipt_email: email,
      automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(
      new HttpError("Payment Form failed to load, please try again", 400)
    );
  }

  res.status(201).json({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
};
```

routes

```
paymentRouter.get("/configure", getConfiguration);

paymentRouter.post("/create-payment-intent", postPaymentIntent);
```

PS: the routes are correct, you cannot see the full fetch path as its in a custom sendRequest hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get automatic payment methods populated in their UI, you'd need to ensure the payment methods are enabled in the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/payment_methods) and the [minimum charge amount](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts) is met. It's likely that some payment methods are not enabled or minimum amount is not met that led to other payment methods not displayed in Payment Element.

As specified in the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-redirect) that:

> Note: Setting if_required requires that you handle successful confirmations for redirect-based and non-redirect based payment methods separately. When a non-redirect based payment method is successfully confirmed, stripe.confirmPayment will resolve with a {paymentIntent} object.

iDEAL (the payment method in the screenshot) is a redirect based payment method for customer to select bank to make payment. Bank dropdown is part of iDEAL payment process and it's required. Since iDEAL is a redirect based payment method, customer will always be redirected to his/her bank page to complete the payment, then return to your website.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I though the amount is in euro but its actually the smallest currency (cents). When I made it more, it worked properly!